# Substitute on quoted arguments

Tags: r

Looking for a way to use substitute on quoted language objects as expression.
`substitute` expects to get lazy expression in `expr`.
To goal is to substitute `.expr` in `expr.template` which is a language objects generated dynamically based on metadata.

```
## data
expr = quote(x <- f(10))
expr.template = quote(g(.expr, flag = TRUE))

## expected output
quote(g(x <- f(10), flag = TRUE))
#g(x <- f(10), flag = TRUE)

## current workaround
h = function(expr, expr.template){
    eval(substitute(
        substitute(
            .expr.template,
            list(.expr = expr)
        ),
        list(.expr.template = expr.template)
    ))
}
h(expr = expr, expr.template = expr.template)
#g(x <- f(10), flag = TRUE)
```

So I would be surprised if there wouldn't be any more canonical way to deal with it. Base R solution preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `do.call`:

```
do.call("substitute", list(expr.template, list(.expr = expr)))
## g(x <- f(10), flag = TRUE)
```

Comment: nice, this way it will cascade for any further substitution when nesting further lists, correct?

Comment: Yes, it will cascade if you need to further substitute into the result.  Of course, if you only need to substitute multiple variables *at once* then the substitution list can have more than one component.